# WinRT - Display animated GIF in a control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need to display an animated GIF in my metro app, but I can't find any control that allows it. (I tried `Image`, `MediaElement` and `MediaPlayer` from the Player Framework)

Is it possible somehow to display an animated GIF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't checked if it works and it might not work for you due to airspace issues - you could try hosting your gif in a WebView control. It might be a lot easier than the otherwise better solutions proposed by Norbert and Carl.

Comment: That worked :)
First I'm detecting the dimensions of the gif and then setting the webviews height and width to that added with 20 to avoid scrolling bars. 
Then just set the source of the webview to the gif and it works :)

Comment: Consider switching to WebViewBrush. That should give you better performance

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this natively by using the BitmapDecoder class in the .NET Framework.  I have an example on my blog, that shows how to implement an AnimationControl that is able to show animated GIFs from a ressource gif file.  Check out: http://www.henrikbrinch.dk/Blog/2013/02/21/Windows-8---GIF-animations--the-RIGHT-way

Answer (score 3):

I just released a library to play animated GIFs: [XamlAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif). You just need to set an attached property on a standard `Image` control:

```
<Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="/Images/animated.gif" />
```

(the xmlns mapping is `xmlns:gif="using:XamlAnimatedGif"`)

In works on WPF, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This can't be natively done but you can check out

http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

which does all you want. 
Also you can check this

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jstegman/archive/2009/09/08/silverlight-3-sample-updates.aspx

which contains a GIF Decoder library

Answer (score 1):

Here You have a good tutorial how to insert gif into Metro Style App:

http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/animated-gifs-in-xamlc/

But simplest way is use this project:

http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

As @Filip Skakun said `WebView` method works. Sure it's "hack" but all these libraries and decoding on fly is slow, animation flickers (at least in windows phone). Using WebView gives you ability to host animated gifs with transparent background. To use WebView gif rendering approach create html page in your project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>gif rendering</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetImageSource(image, source) {
            document.getElementById(image).src = source;
        };
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        -ms-content-zooming:none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-scroll-translation: none;
        -ms-touch-select: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        zoom: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img id="gifPlaceholder" src=""/>

<script>
    SetImageSource("gifPlaceholder", window.top.location.search.substring(1));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is important - because it disables zoom / scrolling / touch-move of WebView (which isn't desirable in most cases). Add animated gifs to same folder (where html sits). Xaml code:

```
<WebView Name="gifRendererWebView" 
         Source="ms-appx-web:///pathToHtmlInProject.html?gifName.gif"
         DefaultBackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

The only drawback is that you "lose gestures" on area which `WebView` occupy (and you can't use `WebViewBrush` because you would lose animation).