# Animated Icons in Windows Phone SDK

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I am working on a weather app (for learning purposes) using Windows Phone SDK and C# as programming language.
I need to display an icon for each type of weather, for example, cloudy, raining, sunny, windy etc. I was wondering about what my options are.
I googled a little and found [this](http://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/). This is a Javascript library. Is there any way I can use this in my xaml page? If not, what are my options to show animated images in xaml?

Comment: In which way have you stored the animated images?

Comment: I have not, so far. I think storing leaves me with the gif options only. Can i use the skycons that i mentioned by any chance?

Comment: You can either convert them to a gif using a screen capture program (I don't knof if that is legal, though) or you can use them inside a browser ellement of your app, but that is very bad style.

Comment: You can achieve this using gif images.Follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183296/winrt-display-animated-gif-in-a-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use javascript based images in XAML.

You have several options here:

1. Use gif images (supported via third party components)
2. Use small videos (MediaElement)
3. Animate it yourself using XAML elements (hardest)
4. Use `WebBrowser` component and then import that js images (might also be hard)

Comment: Can you guide me in a one better direction.  What are some third party components for supporting gifs?

Comment: The choice you make is your own. As for your question, you don't need me to search the internet.